# How to create list by importing txt file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `department.txt` file that contains departments:

```
Chemistry
Physics
Mathematics
Other
```

and i want to create a drop down list `<select>` by importing this file in my HTML. How can i do it using `Javascript`?
There are 50+ departments in file , so creating `<option>` for every department will not be a good idea.

Comment: have you try something ?

Comment: As far as I know javascript will not let you access the file system, so you will not be able to open department.txt with JS.

Comment: @ShailendraSharma yes. I have tried using php to import the file and create list inside javascript. That doesn't work.

Comment: @angelcool.net Alright. is there anyother way to populate the list? like using AJAX or any other mehtod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To read `txt` file, you need to make an `ajax` call to `department.txt` and iterate departments like this:

```js
function readFile() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var res = xhttp.responseText;
      res = res.split('\n');
      var html = '<select name="department">';
      res.forEach(function(item) {
        html += '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
      });
      html += '</select>';
      document.body.innerHTML = html;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "department.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
readFile();
```